# Radius of convergece of Taylor expansion of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Consider the Taylor expansion of the function $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ in powers of $x -\frac{1}{2}$:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^3} = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n(x-\frac{1}{2})^n
$$

What is the radius of convergence of this series?

This question was asked in NBHM doctoral examination 2021.
I am not sure how to compute: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{f^{n+1}(\frac{1}{2})}{(n+1)f^n(\frac{1}{2})}\right|$$
where $f^k(\frac{1}{2})$ is the $k$th derivative at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Is there any other approach other than the usual ratio test one?

Comment: How much complex analysis do you know/are allowed to use?

Comment: See this for an easy way to calculate the radius of convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis

Comment: Thanks! got it @QC_QAOA.